# watermark an image with rotation and opacity using imagick in php

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

How can i apply a watermark onto an image with rotation and opacity using imagick in php

this is my code

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage(realpath('C:\xampp\htdocs\imagick\3.jpg'));

$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage(realpath('C:\xampp\htdocs\imagick\1.png'));

$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;
?>
```

Comment: i want to apply watermark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your watermark image and the image you want to add it to .

Them merge them using [PHP ImageCopy function](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$watermark= imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($watermark);
$sy = imagesy($watermark);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $watermark, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Should do the trick..

In your example you are only missing the rotate image.

```
$imagick->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel('transparent'), -13.55);
```

[Imagick.rotateImage](http://www.php.net//manual/en/imagick.rotateimage.php)

Comment: i tried this but if i have a png image then it loos its transparent

Comment: @user3262732 try using the updated 'transparent' in the constructor of the watermark.